# Private Sub User-Defined Type Not Defined Range Sheet

Tags: vba, excel, compiler-errors

First post. I have the relatively simple code below and am getting a

> User-defined type not defined

error. I know that the stand alone code works when I place it into one Sub but for various reasons I want to split it out so that in my larger workbook I can just call on the second sub rather than having to copy and paste the whole loop multiple times. The purpose of the code is to autosize the specified range in excel.

```
Sub letsGo()
Dim rng As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Range1")
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Call whyDoesntThisWork(sht, rng)
End Sub

Private Sub whyDoesntThisWork(rangeSheet As Sheet, rangeTable As Range)
Dim Col As Range
Dim reSize As Range
For Each Col In rangeTable.Columns
    If Col.Hidden = False Then
        Set reSize = rangeSheet.Range(rangeSheet.Cells(rangeTable.Row, Col.Column), rangeSheet.Cells(rangeTable.Rows.Count, Col.Column)) reSize.Columns.autoFit
    End If
Next Col
End Sub
```

Comment: There is no such type as `Sheet` hence the error.

Comment: Correct, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two different data types:

```
Private Sub whyDoesntThisWork(rangeSheet As Sheet, rangeTable As Range)
```

rangeSheet is a Sheet, but when you call it, you pass:

```
Call whyDoesntThisWork(sht, rng)

sht is of type WorkSheet
```

That's your inconsistency.  I recommend you change your definition to:

```
Private Sub whyDoesntThisWork(rangeSheet As WorkSheet, rangeTable As Range)
```

Comment: FYI - `rangeSheet` can't be a `Sheet`, because there is no such object type as `Sheet`.

Comment: Thanks! Looking back that was really obvious and I can't believe I spent several hours trying to figure it out

Answer (score -1):

Change `rangeSheet As Sheet` to `rangeSheet As Worksheet`